# show text in multiple lines in HTML table cell

Tags: html, css, tablerow

I have this date format **2019-09-13 14:36:06** which I want to insert in table cell such that date comes in first line and time comes in second line like this

```
2019-09-13
14:36:06
```

I tried the following css on table cell for this purpose

```
td{
    white-space:pre;
}
```

But what I am getting is this

```
2019-
09-13 
14:36:06
```

Comment: can u plz send the total html code?

Comment: Where are you getting the date format from?

Comment: date format is a string which I am loading from json using jquery

Answer (score 2):

Probably the result you get is due to the actual width that is within your cell (thus its size).

This is the example:

```css
table { border:solid 1px; }
table tr { border:solid 1px; }
table tr td { border:solid 1px; }
td {
  max-width: 55px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>2019-09-13 14:36:06</td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want try with `white-space:pre;` you need to have the date in your HTML already formatted in two lines, and the formatting will be respected.

```css
table { border:solid 1px; }
table tr { border:solid 1px; }
table tr td { border:solid 1px; }
td {
  
  text-align:center;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>2019-09-13 14:36:06</td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
2019-09-13
14:36:06
    </td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

To my knowledge, however, there are no other pure CSS solutions (perhaps as a very clever hack). The alternative is to use Javascript but it does not seem to be included in your request.

Comment: I am using jquery to get date string from json and add it to table cell

Comment: @harv3 If you can manipulate your date before write it on HTML table the solution can be something like `"2019-09-13 14:36:06".replace(" ", "<br/>");`. If you have trouble manipulating your date, post your JQuery code and we can try to help more.

Comment: I am doing it like this `var dt=date.split(" ");td.append("<span>"+dt[0]+"</span>" +"<span>"+dt[1]+"</span>")` . I also tried as  you mentioned in above comment it is working too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has two way to implement ur question..

1.Add this html code..

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <td><span>2019-09-13</span> <span>14:36:06</span></td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**css**

```
td span {
    display: block;
}
```

2.If its possible, then plz reduce the width of the td..

Comment: The result is same as mentioned after doing as you said. Do I need to increase or decrease td width?

Comment: need to decrease the width.. but that is temporary solution.. so try to use the first one i added..